# 2 servers 2 routers 2 ddns from noip

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ddns

Please have patience and if you answer please explain like you would explain a moron.
I have 2 routers ,router 1 is ppoe and conected with a nuc server and ddns from noip .Router 2 is conected to router 1 with DHCP.and a raspberry pi webserver also another dns from noip .
When I connect wirelessly to router 1 or 2 I can access http://my address.com from raspberry webserver (router 2) without any problems ( when I connect over the web like  4 g ) connection is refused . Raspberry pi also have a ddns from noip. DMZ is activated for Nuc server on router 1. If I stop DMZ on router 1 I can't access anymore Nuc webserver which is conected to router 1. Now, my question is , why I can't access raspberry webserver over the internet?
I would like also to take this opportunity to thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Iíiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.